# calling a function on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have written the script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Click").click(function(){
            var data1 = new Object();
            data1.name = $('#databases').val();
            $.ajax({
          url : "form_submit",
          type : 'POST',
          data : data1,
          dataType : "text",              
          success : function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
            output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "REPORTSUITE_ID" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "REPORTSUITE_NAME" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "STAGING_DATABASE" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "DWH_DATABASE" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
            for (var i in data)
            {
                output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].REPORTSUITE_ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button type = \"buttion\" id =\"tableList\">" + data[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "</button>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].STAGING_DATABASE + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].DWH_DATABASE + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            }
            output += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
          }
          });
        });
        });
    $("#tableList").click(function(){
            alert("this is data");
            });
</script>
```

On the clicking of button with id = tableList, i want the alert with message "this is data" to be displayed but it does not display anything.
    I also tried with pasting the code related to click of button with id tableList between different  tags, still it did not work.
    Please help

Comment: When `$("#tableList").click()` is executed, that element doesn’t exist in the DOM yet. Either execute this after the element has been added to the DOM, or use _event delegation_.

Comment: And IDs have to be unique within an HTML document – and since you are creating elements in a loop, you will be generating the same ID multiple times. Either append something like an index to the id value, or use a class instead.

Comment: I wrote the code between separate <script> tags and and also that was to run when document got ready with this ----$(document).ready(function(){, but still it did not work so please tell me how to do it. Also i do not know event delegation

Comment: I tried with class, it did not work

Comment: _“I tried with class, it did not work”_ – if elements with that class don’t exist at the time zou bind the event handler, then that’s the same situation. _“Also i do not know event delegation”_ – well then research it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi used event delegation for the above question as pointed out as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){
        $("#placeholder").on("click","button",function(event){
            alert("id is " + this.id + "for database " + $('#databases').val())
        })
    });
</script>
```

The value is being passed correctly. Thanks for the pointer.